# How to name files using gettext translations with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, gettext

I'm using gettext translation adapter in a Zend Framework projekt. But I'm wondering what's the best practise when naming and placing these translation files within my project?

At first I had `APPLICATION_PATH/languages/sv_SE.po (and sv_SE.mo)`
But then I read about the auto searching features of Zend Framework and started wondering if it would be better to have the languages in subfolders. But the structure `APPLICATION_PATH/languages/sv_SE/sv_SE.po and APPLICATION_PATH/languages/en_US/en_US.po` didn't feel quite natural. Using array adapters ect it have felt easier to come up with a good naming conventions... But what is the best practise when it comes to using gettext translations in Zend Framework? Is it most common to have all translations in a  single file or should one use something like

```
APPLICATION_PATH/languages/en_US/admin.po
APPLICATION_PATH/languages/en_US/forms.po
APPLICATION_PATH/languages/en_US/othercrap.po
```

Feels like this apporach might make it tedious when scaning source for strings to translate since one would have to open several files etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
APPLICATION_PATH/languages/en_US/admin.po
APPLICATION_PATH/languages/en_US/forms.po
APPLICATION_PATH/languages/en_US/othercrap.po
```

which has worked fine.